# Importing parallel python module. Module not recognized

Tags: python, tweepy, python-module

I have a project directory for pulling and processing twitter data with a config module for all my configurations

```
twitter_data
|
|--config
|   |--configAuth.py -> a class file for configuring an api object
|   |--accessKeys.py -> a file for processing access keys for configuration
|   |--__init__.py -> used for global API
|   |--access_keys.txt
|
|--dataScraping
    |--searchUsers.py -> test file to see if twitter API works
    |--__init__.py
```

this is the contents of the searchUsers.py

```
import tweepy
from config import api
from config.configAuth import configAuth


def configTweepy(keys):
    return configAuth(keys).getApi()


def getUserList(keyWord):
    return api.search_users(keyWord)


users = getUserList('rock music')
for user in users: print(user.screen_name)
```

When I run it, I am met with this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "searchUsers.py", line 7, in <module>
    from config import api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

I tried using the sys.append path method, but I need it to only work with files in the twitter_data directory without having to specify the full path because `accessKeys.py` relies on the `access_keys.txt` file.
Are there any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running `searchUsers.py` with `dataScraping` as your working directory.

Make sure you are running from the `twitter_data` folder as your working directory.

You should do it by `python -m dataScraping.searchUsers`